# Pause VBA Script While Links Update

Tags: excel, vba, pause

This is my second post about this macro. Although the first post received a few responses, none of the responses solved the problem (thank you for responding though).

Scenario: 
I have about 20 sub-spreadsheets with links to external sources. The number of links per spreadsheet varies from about 500 to 10,000. A master spreadsheet calls macros to open each sub-spreadsheet in turn and update the links.
Each sub-spreadsheet has a dashboard that tells me how many links remain to be updated. This is done by counting the number of “N/A” values in each tab, then summing these counts in cell A20. As the links are updated, the value in A20 counts down to zero.

```
Sub Sub01()
    Dim NAtotal As Integer

    Set ActiveWKB = Workbooks.Open("Sub01.xlsm")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.CalculateFull
    ActiveWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources

    NAtotal = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(20, "C").Value
    MsgBox (NAtotal)    'Tells me how many cells remain to be updated – starts off at 4450.

    NAtotal = 100   'Debugging effort to let me know that NAtotal does adjust.
    MsgBox (NAtotal)

    Do Until NAtotal = 0
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       MsgBox (NAtotal) 'Another debugging effort to monitor NAtotal. Starts at 100, then jumps to (and remains at) 4450 on the second loop and all subsequent loops.

       NAtotal = Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(20, "C").Value   'Resets NAtotal to the value in C20. This never changes, but remains at 4450.

       DoEvents

    Loop

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    MsgBox ("Done")

    Sheets("Dashboard").Activate
    Range("B1").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub`
```

The macro should continue to loop until cell A20 hits zero, and then stop.
Cell A20 does count down, but variable NAtotal remains at its initial value.

Any guidance/recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: Hi I think I have seen a similar issue before but not quiet sure if it is the same. I believe it is linked to the Workbooks.open that is causing the issue. Have you tried running the same procedure on one of the sub spreadsheet without opening it via the master spreadsheet? Give it a go and if the value updates then my theory might be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion RCL. I copied and edited the code from the master to the sub, and launched the macro with the sub already open, with the same results. I commented everything from the Do Until loop to the end and it ran fine - the screen updated with the proper counts. Kind of defeats the purpose as I want to chain a series of macros together to update all sub-spreadsheets in succession.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the code below worked for me. Try use the same method instead of using a loop. The schedule will trigger every second until the NATotal = 0 logically anyway. Just update the code to fit your references.

```
Public firstOpen As Boolean

Sub testForm()
Dim cellCount As Integer
Dim s1 As Sheet1
Set s1 = Sheet1
Dim cellCol As Integer
Dim activeWbk As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

If firstOpen = False Then
 firstOpen = True
 Set activeWbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Example\Link2.xlsm")
 Set ws = activeWbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.CalculateFull
 activeWbk.UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources
 CreateNewSchedule
 Exit Sub
Else
 Set activeWbk = Workbooks("Link2.xlsm")
 Set ws = activeWbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
End If


cellCount = ws.Range("N2").Value



If cellCount = 0 Then
 MsgBox ("Done...")
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 firstOpen = false 
Else
  Debug.Print cellCount
  CreateNewSchedule

End If

'Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

End Sub

Sub CreateNewSchedule()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Procedure:="testForm", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```